# What algorithm can be used to pack groups of items into grid

Tags: algorithm, datagrid, bin-packing

I have a bunch of buttons which each belong to a certain group, and I want to pack them into a grid wasting as little space as possible.

In know it is something like bin packing, but a little different, isn't it?

For example, I have three groups, A, B and C. Group A contains 17 items, group B contains 7 items, and group C has 8 items. A good output for this would be

```
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┰───┬───┬───┐
│ A │ A │ A │ A │ A ┃ B │ B │ B │
├───┼───┼───┼───╆━━━╃───┼───┼───┤
│ A │ A │ A │ A ┃ B │ B │ B │ B │
├───┼───┼───┼───╊━━━┿━━━┿━━━┿━━━┥
│ A │ A │ A │ A ┃ C │ C │ C │ C │
├───┼───┼───┼───╂───┼───┼───┼───┤
│ A │ A │ A │ A ┃ C │ C │ C │ C │
└───┴───┴───┴───┸───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

It doesn't have to be square, in fact it would be even better it it did prefer a landscape rectangle.

Here's another example: Four groups, A, B, C and D. Group A has 7 items, B has 3 items, C has 1 item and D has 5 items. A possible output I'd wish for would be:

```
┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
│ A │ A │ A │ A │
├───┼───┼───╆━━━┥
│ A │ A │ A ┃ D │
┝━━━┿━━━┿━━━╋━━━┥
│ C │ C │ C ┃ B │
├───┼───╆━━━╃───┤
│ C │ C ┃ B │ B │
└───┴───┸───┴───┘
```

Comment: you should explain why the obvious solutions, like just laying down all the As, Bs, Cs, and Ds in zig-zag order, are not acceptable

Comment: Well, as seen in the second example just placing them in zig zag order yould not always yield the most optimal result

Comment: We need you to describe better how to evaluate a solution.  You state that the zig-zag solution isn't "most optimal", but haven't explained the principles behind that statement -- or related discrimination.

Comment: How do you define "wasted space?" Once you do this, I think you'll have better answers.